# use polar coordinates to evaluate the integral $\int^2_0 \int^{\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}}_0 \frac{y}{y^2 + x^2} dydx$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

use polar coordinates to evaluate the integral $\int^2_0 \int^{\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}}_0 \frac{y}{y^2 + x^2} dydx$

I have no problem evaluating the integral but the limits of integraation is what I am iffy on. Would it be $ 0 < r < 2cos\theta $ and $0< \theta <\pi/2 $? or is it $ 0 <\theta < \pi $ and $0< r < 1 $

Comment: I'm wondering if perhaps you have a typo in the integral, and the upper limit of the inner integral should instead read $\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}$. That would make the conversion to polar coordinates make more sense.

Comment: hi @DavidH yes sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For the corrected integral:**

The upper boundary of the region of integration is $y=\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}$, so it’s the upper half of $y^2=1-(1-x)^2$, or $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$, the circle of radius $1$ centred at $\langle 1,0\rangle$. Since $x$ runs from $0$ to $2$, the region of integration is simply the upper half of the disk of radius $1$ centred at $\langle 1,0\rangle$.

The angle $\theta$ is $0$ along the base of the region, and for $0\le\alpha<\frac{\pi}2$ the line with polar equation $\theta=\alpha$ crosses the region, so the limits of integration on $\theta$ must be $0$ and $\frac{\pi}2$. Clearly for each of these values of $\theta$ the lower limit on $r$ is $0$. The upper limit would be a bit messy, except that we know that the polar equation of the circle with radius $1$ and centre $\langle 1,0\rangle$ is ...

Comment: Sorry I wrote down the integral wrong. It has been fixed now, it should have read  $\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}$

Comment: wouldn't it be the disk with radius $1$ centered at $(1,1)$ ?

Comment: @Alex: No, in that case it would be $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=1$.

Comment: sorry I got a little bit confused, I thought you meant the closed ball $B(0,1)$ , so the upper limit for $r$ would be $cos\theta$ ?

Comment: @Alex: Yes: that circle has the polar equation $r=\cos\theta$.

Comment: ok, my only question is, is that when you solve for $(x-1)^2 + y^2 =1$ and solve for polar coordinates you get that $r = 2cos\theta$? I thought that this would be the upper limit for r

Comment: @Alex: I do apologize: I must not have hit the $2$ key hard enough, because I certainly meant to type $r=2\cos\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all $\sqrt{1-(1-x^2)}=\sqrt{x^2}=x$ for $x\geq 0$. Now I encourage you to make a sketch of the area over which is being integrated (it is a triangle with vertices $(0,0),(0,2)\text{ and }(2,0)$). Now for a given value of $\theta$ (the angle with the $x$ axis) the radius $r$ can go from $0$ to $2\cos\theta$. And $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\arctan{2/2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote down the integral wrong. It has been fixed now. the upper limit should have read $\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}$